# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when transforming XML using XSLT

Tags: java, xml, scala, xslt, playframework

I am using the Java `javax.xml.transform` library in my Scala Play application to perform a simple XSLT transformation on some XML. I am trying to remove the namespace from one of the elements, but I am getting an exception when I POST XML to the endpoint which does the transformation.

The method I have written to do the transformation is below:

```
def transformXml(xml: String, xslName: String): Try[String] = {
  Try {
    // Create transformer factory
    val factory: TransformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance()

    // Use the factory to create a template containing the xsl file
    val template: Templates = factory.newTemplates(new StreamSource(new FileInputStream(s"app/xsl/$xslName.xsl")))

    // Use the template to create a transformer
    val xformer: Transformer = template.newTransformer()

    // Prepare the input for transformation
    val input: Source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml))

    // Prepare the output for transformation result
    val outputBuffer: Writer = new StringWriter
    val output: javax.xml.transform.Result = new StreamResult(outputBuffer)

    // Apply the xslt transformation to the input and store the result in the output
    xformer.transform(input, output)

    // Return the transformed XML
    outputBuffer.toString
  }
}
```

Through putting `println`s in my code, I have deduced that it is in fact failing at the `xformer.transform(input, output)` line. The XML I am passing in and the XSL file I am using to transform are below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Message xmlns="http://foo.bar" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance">
    <EnvelopeVersion>2.0</EnvelopeVersion>
    <Header>
        <MessageDetails>
            ...
            ...
            ...
        </MessageDetails>
        <SenderDetails/>
    </Header>
    <OtherDetails>
        <Keys/>
    </OtherDetails>
    <Body>
    </Body>
</Message>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:param name="ancestralNamespace" select="namespace-uri(/*[1])"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
                <xsl:with-param name="ancestralNamespace" select="$ancestralNamespace"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[contains(namespace-uri(),'foo.bar')]">
        <xsl:param name="ancestralNamespace" select="namespace-uri(..)"/>
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
                <xsl:with-param name="ancestralNamespace" select="$ancestralNamespace"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My expected output is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Message>
        <EnvelopeVersion>2.0</EnvelopeVersion>
        <Header>
            <MessageDetails>
                ...
                ...
                ...
            </MessageDetails>
            <SenderDetails/>
        </Header>
        <OtherDetails>
            <Keys/>
        </OtherDetails>
        <Body>
        </Body>
    </Message>
```

The error I get back from sending a POST request to my endpoint is this:

```
{
    "statusCode": 500,
    "message": "javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1"
}
```

I do not have much experience with XSLT and have inherited this code from someone else to try to debug, so if anyone with XML/XSLT experience could give me some help I would greatly appreciate it. The perplexing thing is that the person I got this problem from had written Unit Tests using this method (send in my example XML and get out the expected XML) and they passed so I don't know where to look next.

Comment: Start by catching the exception and producing a stack trace.

Comment: After a few hours of throwing everything I could think of at this, I found the solution! Left it as an answer to this post. The stack trace in my console really wasn't very helpful in the end - just kept badgering me about the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error.

Comment: It might be worth noting that if that is your actual XSLT, then the `ancestralNamespace` parameter is not actually being used anywhere. It is simply being set to a default value, and passed around, but not actually used. If it is `<xsl:param name="ancestralNamespace" select="namespace-uri(/*[1])"/>` that is causing the problem, you could just change the XSLT to remove all instances of the `xsl:param` (and `xsl:with-param`). See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rM1

Comment: @TimC I would've done something like that, but this XSLT is one I received from my work and I wasn't allowed to modify it. Made my life a little harder but oh well. This suggestion would definitely be helpful if I'd had the opportunity to modify the XSLT though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right so after a few hours of debugging and fretting over this, I found the solution!

The default transformer which my Play application was using handles XSLT differently, and was getting confused at the line `<xsl:param name="ancestralNamespace" select="namespace-uri(/*[1])"/>`. What solved my issue was to use a different transformer. The one I found to work was Xalan (version 2.7.2), and after importing that into my project build file I hit the endpoint and the transformation was successful.

To import the version I found to work, add the following to your build:

```
"xalan" % "xalan" % "2.7.2" % "runtime"
```

I believe that the "runtime" section is the most important part, as it seems to overwrite what the application would normally use. I would guess that the reason my tests passed but my endpoint failed is that Scala Test runs with different configuration to runtime. Nothing else about my code had to be changed.

I hope this helps to stop anyone else from encountering this (admittedly rather unique) error! I ended up trawling through countless forums from as far back as 2002 before resorting to trying a different runtime configuration.